# Get a Field Object, not FieldInfo, from a VB Class Instance

Tags: vb.net, reflection

I am trying to iterate through objects (fields) in a class and invoke a method on each object. Each object is of a different type. Here is the parent class:

```
Public Class MySettings
    Public IdentifyByFacType As RadioButtonSetting

    Public WtrFacTypes As ListSetting
    Public OilFacTypes As ListSetting

    Public GroupByRef As CheckboxSetting
    Public GroupRefAttr As TxtboxSetting
End Class
```

Here is part of one of the sub-object classes:

```
<Serializable>
Public Class TxtboxSetting
    <XmlIgnore()>
    Public MyControl As Windows.Forms.TextBox
    <XmlIgnore()>
    Public DefaultSetting As String

    Private _SavedSetting As String

    Public Property SavedSetting As String
        Get
            Return _SavedSetting
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _SavedSetting = value
            CurrentValue = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(DefaultSetting As String, MyControl As Windows.Forms.TextBox)
        Me.DefaultSetting = DefaultSetting
        Me.MyControl = MyControl
    End Sub

    Public Sub RestoreDefault()
        CurrentValue = DefaultSetting
    End Sub
End Class
```

All of the sub-objects of the `MySettings` class, like `GroupRefAttr` for example, have the same methods and properties, but the internal code is different.

So I will have several classes like the `MySettings` class, and each one will have different sub-objects. Given an instance of such a class, I want to automatically iterate through the fields and call a method `RestoreDefault` on each one. I don't want to have to know what objects exist in the `MySettings` class. Rather, knowing that they all have the `RestoreDefault`method, I want simply call the method on each object.

Despite much searching, I have not found a way to do this. With reflection, I can only get this far:

```
Dim Opts as New MySettings
For Each var In Opts.GetType.GetFields
    Dim RestoreDefault As System.Reflection.MethodInfo = var.FieldType.GetMethod("RestoreDefault")
    RestoreDefault.Invoke(Opts, Nothing)
Next
```

However, in the line `RestoreDefault.Invoke(Opts, Nothing)`, I can't just pass in `Opts`, as I am dealing with a field in `Opts`, not `Opts` itself. A statement like this would work: `RestoreDefault.Invoke(Opts.GroupRefAttr, Nothing)`, but that requires me to know the objects in the `MySettings` class ahead of time, and that defeats the purpose. Is there a way to grab field instance objects at runtime and pull this off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you invoke the `RestoreDefault` method you need to invoke it on the setting (i.e., the value of the field), not the class containing the setting. Changing your code to this should fix your problem:

```
Dim Opts as New MySettings
For Each var In Opts.GetType.GetFields
    Dim setting As Object = var.GetValue(Opts)
    Dim RestoreDefault As System.Reflection.MethodInfo = var.FieldType.GetMethod("RestoreDefault")
    RestoreDefault.Invoke(setting, Nothing)
Next
```

However, if you introduce either a base class or an interface you should be able to get rid of some or all of the reflection. The container setting class can have a collection of settings that each have a shared base class or interface with a `RestoreDefault` method. The container setting class will then call this method through the base class or interface without having to use reflection.

The base class:

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseSetting
    Public MustOverride Sub RestoreDefault
End Class
```

A specific settings class:

```
Public Class TxtboxSetting
    Inherits BaseSetting

    Public Overrides Sub RestoreDefault()
        ' Specific implementation
    End Sub
End Class
```

On any class deriving from `BaseSetting` you can now call the `RestoreDefault` method without having to use reflection.

However, considering your design you might still want to use reflection to get the settings containd in the `MySettings` class. You can do it like this:

```
Dim settings = From fieldInfo in Opts.GetType.GetFields
               Where GetType(BaseSetting).IsAssignableFrom(fieldInfo.FieldType)
               Select DirectCast(fieldInfo.GetValue(Opts), BaseSetting)
For Each setting In settings
    setting.RestoreDefault()
Next
```

Reflection is used to find all the fields deriving from `BaseSetting` and then `RestoreDefault` is called on each field. This method does not suffer from the "magic string" problem where your code depends on the name of the `RestoreDefault` method represented in a string.

(Also, calling the `MySettings` class the *parent* is a bit misleading because there is nothing inheriting from `MySettings`. Instead this class contains other settings.)

Comment: This does solve the problem! Regarding collections and a base class, I probably wasn't entirely clear. While the methods and properties have the same **names**, the datatypes for parameters and properties are different (e.g. string for textbox, decimal for numeric, etc.). Hence, I don't see how to implement a base class and maintain strong typing, which I am reluctant to drop. It's possible my entire idea here is flawed...

Comment: @BenW. I have added some information about how you can use a base class combined with reflection.

Answer (score 0):

> All of the sub-objects of the MySettings class, like GroupRefAttr for example, have the same methods and properties, but the internal code is different.

In that case, the sub-object types should be defined such that they implement a common interface that demands these same methods and properties exist. For now, I'll name that interface `IControlSetting`. Then, your `For` loop looks something like this:

```
Dim Opts as New MySettings
For Each var In Opts.GetType.GetFields
    Dim setting As IControlSetting = TryCast(var.GetValue(Opts), IControlSetting)
    If setting Is Nothing Then Continue
    setting.RestoreDefault()
Next
```

Additionally, I'd change your `MySettings` type to encapsulate a dictionary or `IControlSetting` objects. Then you can just iterate the dictionary to check each of the objects, rather than needing reflection. That might look like this:

```
Public Class MySettings
    Private allSettings As Dictionary(Of String, IControlSetting)

    Public Sub New()
       allSettings = new Dictionary(Of String, IControlSetting)()

       allSettings.Add("IdentifyByFacType", New RadioButtonSetting())
       allSettings.Add("WtrFacTypes", New ListSetting())
       allSettings.Add("OilFacTypes", New ListSetting())
       '... 
    End Sub

    Public Property IdentifyByFacType As RadioButtonSetting
        Get
            Return DirectCast(allSettings("IdentifyByFacType"), RadioButtonSetting)
        End Get
        'The setters may be optional, depending on how you expect to use these
        Set(ByVal value As RadioButtonSetting)
            allSettings("IdentifyByFacType") = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property WtrFacTypes As ListSetting
        Get
            Return DirectCast(allSettings("WtrFacTypes"), RadioButtonSetting)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ListSetting)
            allSettings("WtrFacTypes") = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property OilFacTypes As ListSetting
        Get
            Return DirectCast(allSettings("OilFacTypes"), RadioButtonSetting)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ListSetting)
            allSettings("OilFacTypes") = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '...


    Public Sub RestoreAllDefaults()
        For Each setting As KeyValuePair(Of String, IControlSetting) In allSettings
            setting.Value.RestoreDefault()
        Next setting
    End Sub     

End Class
```